# How to create an array of objects by iterating through Observable<Object[]>

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Im having a Google Firestore collection called `users` which has the below format :

```
{
  "contactNumber":"0123456789",
  "email":"johndoe@gmail.com",
  "location":[7.2906° N,80.6337° E],
  "isOnline":false,
  "name":"John"
}
```

the field `location` is in the `geopint` data type. Im fetching the users records in my service as below :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { Marker } from '../models/marker';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
    users: Observable<User[]>;
    markers:Marker[];

    constructor(firestore: AngularFirestore) {
       this.users = firestore.collection('users').valueChanges();
    }

    getUsers(){
       return this.users;
    }

    getUserMarkers(){

    }
}
```

the property `users` is now having the records as an Observable.

What i want to achieve here is, i have a separate model called `Marker`. I want to create an array of markers for each user record using the fields in the users records and return it from `getUserMarkers` function.

Marker model:

```
export interface Marker {
 name?:String;
 longitute?:Number;
 latitude?:Number;
 isOnline?:boolean;
}
```

`longitute` and `latitude` fields should be set using the `location` in user and other corresponding values ie name and isOnline.
What would be the better way to do this?

Update :

Using one of the answers I came up with this.

```
 getUserMarkers() {
    return this.getUsers().pipe(map(users => {
         users.map(user => {
            return {
            name: user.name,
            longitute: user.location._long,
            latitude: user.location._lat,
            isOnline: user.isOnline
            }
        });
    })); 
 }
```

And from the component im trying to assign to this to a property like this.

```
export class MapComponent implements AfterViewInit {
@ViewChild("mapContainer", { static: false }) gmap: ElementRef;
map: google.maps.Map;
markers: Marker[];

constructor(private userService : UserService) {

  this.userService.getUserMarkers().subscribe(markers => {
     this.markers = markers;
   });
}
```

There its giving an error `Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Marker[]'.` where im trying to assign the array to the property `this.markers = markers;`
There

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your array as an observable, you can add use the `map` function to format your data the way you want. The location might need some formatting to strip off the `° N`, `° S`, `° E`, and `° W`.

**Observable**

```
getUserMarkers() {
    return this.getUsers().pipe(map(users => {
         return users.map(user => {
            return {
                name: user.name,
                longitute: user.geopoint._long,
                latitude: user.geopoint._lat,
                isOnline: user.isOnline
            }
        });
    })); 
 }
```

If you want a pure array, you will need to declare a separate variable and possibly use the async/await meathods

**separate variable**

```
markerArray = [];
getUserMarkers() {
    this.getUsers().subscribe(markers => {
        this.markerArray = markers.map(user => {
          return {
            name: user.name,
            longitute: user.location[0]
            latitude: user.location[0]
            isOnline: user.isOnline
          }
        });
    }); 
}
```

**async/await**

```
async getUsers(){
    return this.users;
}

async getUserMarkers() {
    let markerArray = [];
    await this.getUsers().subscribe(markers => {
        markerArray = markers.map(user => {
          return {
            name: user.name,
            longitute: user.location[0]
            latitude: user.location[0]
            isOnline: user.isOnline
          }
        });
    }); 

    return markerArray;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to return an Observable from `getUserMarkers()` ?

Comment: @jsb9009 yes, that should be the first option (`return this.getUsers().pipe(map(user => {`)

Comment: In your first option, its not possible to access the field `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'User[]'.`

Comment: sorry there was a compilation error so had to change as its viewed in the updated question. please have a look

Comment: @jsb9009 you were super close. you need to return your `users.map(`. I updated my answer and I apologize, I am dong this without checking my code because I don't want to spin up a new environment for this.